# how to get skeleton from 3d mesh having verts and faces

Tags: python, mesh, cgal, open3d

I am trying to extract skeleton line from the 3D mesh in python. Something like mentioned in https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Surface_mesh_skeletonization/index.html But I couldnot find any python library examples for this purpose. Any documentations or help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This package is not part of the cgal-swig-bindings for now.

Answer (score 0):

read IEEE, Spherical-Based Three Dimensional Cassava Root Skeleton Extraction, Amares Kaewpunya;